# Ruby style blocks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, closures

But what I'd like to do is have an ability to pass arbitrary code in JavaScript that will be executed in a particular scope, similar to how you can yield blocks in Ruby.

Take this for example:

```
function injectHook() {
    return function(block) {
        block();
    }
}

(function() {
    var a = 1;
    self.inject = injectHook();
})();

inject(function() {
    a++;
});

inject(function() {
    console.log(a);
});
```

The attempt above won't work because `injectHook` is defined at different scope and will not be able to access `a`.

The main use case here is for live debugging of complex code.

Edit: [I started a GitHub project around this question](https://github.com/kristopolous/_inject)

Comment: This question is not at all clear. You certainly can "say" those statements. What do you expect to **happen** when you "say" them? And what do you mean by "self" in that code?  That's not a JavaScript concept, really. Did you mean `this` ?

Comment: I tried to be a little more clear there. Hopefully it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
function Inject(scope) {
    return 'Inject.' + scope + ' = ' + function(block) {
        return eval('(' + block + ')()');
    };
}

(function(){
    var a = 1;
    eval(Inject('ref'));
})();

Inject.ref(function(){ a++ });
Inject.ref(function(){ console.log('hello world', a) });
```

Comment: I like your solution, I also provided an answer that is slightly more ruby-ish. Great question either way!

Comment: Not all browsers decompile functions, mainly mobile browsers, but some minimalistic desktop ones as well

Comment: So I tried this on my friends iPhone and on my Android phone in the Webkit and the Opera browser.  I'm using document.write for compatibility: http://qaa.ath.cx/inject.html .. if you have any counter examples please tell me. I'd like to know. Otherwise, I'll mark this as done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that's not possible in JavaScript. Code only has access to the scope in which it was defined in, and you can't ever get access to local variables that are out-of-scope.

The only way to do something similar is on an object:

```
function injectHook( obj ){
    return function( block ){
        block.apply( obj );
    }
}

function someClass(){
    this.a = 1;

    this.inject = injectHook( this );
}

var instance = new someClass;
instance.inject(function(){
    this.a++;
});
```

(Note: older versions of Firefox have a "bug" in `eval` that makes what you are trying to do possible, but it's not widely possible.)

Comment: are you saying that `function f(){
 var a = 1;
 eval('alert(a)');
}
f();` won't work in say, FF 5?

Comment: No, older versions of FF had code that allowed you to get that `a` variable from outside of function `f`.

Comment: @cwolves what??  how could you possibly get at a local variable in a closure from code not lexically scoped to that closure?

Comment: @Pointy - There are several examples of this if you look around.  Here is one: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/EvalBreaksClosureEncapsulation - There was a huge push for the mozilla team to take this out once it was discovered.  They removed it, quickly.

Comment: Ah.  Well that's pretty interesting. I'm glad they fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, great question! I spent at least an hour trying to come up with a relatively simple way of implementing it! This is how I tackled this problem:

```
Object.prototype.yield = function() {
    return "try { (" + this + ")() } catch (e) { console.log('**Context error** ' + e) }";
}

// first yielding block
var y1 = (Object(function() { 
    console.log('in y1, but still in the right context...');
    a++;
})).yield();

// second yielding block
var y2 = (Object(function() { 
    console.log('in y2, but still in the right context...');
    a = a + 5;
})).yield();

// voila
(function() {
    var a = 1;
    eval(y1);
    eval(y2);
    a--;
    eval(y2);
    console.log(a); // a == 11 now as expected
})();

// another block without an `a`
(function() {
    var b = 1;
    eval(y1); // gracefully fails
})();
```

This tends to be slightly more ruby-ish in the sense that it can yield in multiple locations. Not only that, but it goes a step further by being able to yield to particular blocks of code (`y1`, `y2`, `y3`, etc..)

I hope this answer was useful, your question was great!

Comment: not bad.  I think you could get really close to knuths cofunctions with a solution like this.

Comment: edited slightly making the code more readable (also didn't need the reflection function)